# Check whether String2 is substring of string1 with '*' and '\'

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

Given two strings s1 and s2, we have to check if s2 is a substring of s1.
If it's true print "true" else print "false"
But s1 and s2 can contain characters like '*' and '\'.
In s2, '*' represents zero or more characters in between two alphabets and '\' represents an escape sequence for '*'.
In s1, '*' and '\' are just other characters that are to be checked.

**Sample Input and Output:**

```
Input: abcd , a*c   Output: true
Input : spoon , sp*n  Output : true
Input : regex , re*g    Output : true
Input : search , *c Output : true
Input : zoho , *o*o Output : true
Input : zoho , *ogo Output : false
Input : test , pest Output : false
Input : st*r , t\*r Output : true
Input : star , t\*r Output false
Input : tree , tr\  Output false
Input : tr\e , tr\  Output true
```

I know this question can be solved easily by using **regex**, but **I need a logical approach** for solving this. Can anybody help me soon?
Below is my code that I have tried, but couldn't solve entirely.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = sc.next();
        String s2 = sc.next();
        boolean flag = true;
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(;s2.charAt(j)<'a' || s2.charAt(j)>'z';j++);
        
        for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
            char ch = s1.charAt(i);
            
            if(ch==s2.charAt(j))
            {
                i++;j++;
                break;
                
            }
        }

            for(;j<s2.length();)
            {
                
                System.out.println(i+" "+j);
                while(s2.charAt(j)=='*' && j<s2.length()-1 && s2.charAt(j+1)!=s1.charAt(i) && i<s1.length())
                {
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
                if(i==s1.length())
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                
                if(s1.charAt(i)!=s2.charAt(j) && s2.charAt(j)<97 && s2.charAt(j)>122)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        System.out.print(flag);
        
    }
```

Comment: Do tou thing that regex is not logic?

Comment: This is a question asked in the Interview. They need not want me to solve this by using regex. Otherwise, I agree, regex is also logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the string of * and break it whenever you encounter the * character and check if substrings are in the actual string. Something like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.next();
    String s2 = sc.next();

    int begIndex = 0;
    int prevIndex = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    s2 = stripLeadingAndTrailingCharacter(s2, '*');

    for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); ++i) {
      if ((( i == 0 || s2.charAt(i - 1) != '\\') && s2.charAt(i) == '*')
          || (i == s2.length() - 1))  {
        int endIndex = i == s2.length() - 1 ? i + 1 : i;
        String str = s2.substring(begIndex, endIndex).replace("\\*", "*");
        if (s1.contains(str) && prevIndex <= s1.indexOf(str)) {
          prevIndex = s1.indexOf(str);
        } else {
          flag = false;
          break;
        }
        begIndex = i + 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(flag);
  }

  public static String stripLeadingAndTrailingCharacter(String s, char ch) {
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < s.length(); index++) {
      if (s.charAt(index) != ch) {
        break;
      }
    }
    s = s.substring(index);
    for (index = s.length() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      if (s.charAt(index) != ch) {
        break;
      }
    }
    s = s.substring(0, index + 1);
    return s;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the Answer! This is what I've been looking for. So, stripping the leading and trailing '*'s is the key to solve this problem?

Comment: s1 = "edit"
s2 = "it*ed" ;
In this test case, the answer should be false, but it prints true. Order of the substring should not be changed. Can you update your answer for this?

Comment: Updated to care about indexes, check now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what what you mean with the * and the /, but, one solution to know if a string is a substring for another one is using "contains" method, that extends from String class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "abcdefghi";
    String str2 = "abcd";
    
    if (str1.contains(str2)) {
        System.out.println("Exist the substring.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not exist.");
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that you also needs to replace if exist * or / as a valid value

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. But anyway thanks!